# Apex Test Class throwing NullPointerException

Tags: apex, code-coverage, failing-tests

**UPDATE**

- `NullPointerException` error has been resolved (thanks @Adrian)
- `INVALID_PERSON_ACCOUNT_OPERATION` error was resolved by adding a `RecTypeId` variable
- Now I am confronted by an insert error: `REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [ContactId]: [ContactId]` (stack trace is `Class.lifeEventNotifyControllerTest.TestSOQL: line 24, column 1`)

Since I am looking at the Person Account, `dummyContact.Id` isn't an option, so I tried `dummyContact.PersonContactId` but that threw the same error. What am I missing?

**Updated Apex Test**

```
@isTest
private class lifeEventNotifyControllerTest { 

    static testMethod void TestSOQL() {
        String loggedUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        String RecTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE (Name='Person Account') AND (SobjectType='Account')].Id;
        
        Account dummyContact = new Account();
        dummyContact.RecordTypeID = RecTypeId;
        dummyContact.Firstname = 'Test';
        dummyContact.Lastname = 'Contact';
        dummyContact.PersonBirthdate = date.today();
        dummyContact.Contact_Type__pc = 'Sponsor';
        INSERT dummyContact;

        Account dummyAcct = new Account();
        dummyAcct.Name = 'Test Company';
        dummyAcct.Custom__c = loggedUserId;
        INSERT dummyAcct;

        AccountContactRelation acr = new AccountContactRelation();
        acr.ContactId = dummyContact.PersonContactId;
        acr.AccountId = dummyAcct.Id;
        INSERT acr;

        lifeEventNotifyController testCont = new lifeEventNotifyController ();
        List<AccountContactRelation> dummyList = testCont.getLifeEvents();

        System.assert(dummyList  != null);
        
    }
}
```

**Original Question:**

I am brand new to Apex development and am learning about the importance of code coverage. Right now I have a very simple Apex class querying the AccountContactRelation object via SOQL. When trying to create an Apex test class, I continue to get the following error:

> "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object" error.

Browsing StackExchange I believe this error has to do with my Account and Contact objects not being initialized in the test class?

**Apex Class**

```
public with sharing class lifeEventNotifyController {
  @AuraEnabled
  public List<AccountContactRelation> getLifeEvents() {
    // get current user id
    String loggedUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    List<AccountContactRelation> lifeEventList = [SELECT Id, ContactId, Contact.Name, Contact.Birthdate, AccountId, Account.Name FROM AccountContactRelation WHERE Account.Custom__c = :loggedUserId AND (Contact.Days_to_Birthday__c <= 7 OR Contact.Days_to_Birthday__c = 365)];
    
    return lifeEventList;

  }
}
```

NOTE: In the above class, `Days_to_Birthday__c` is a formula field based on the `Contact.Birthdate` date field.

**Apex Test Class**

```
@isTest
private class lifeEventNotifyControllerTest { 

    static testMethod void TestSOQL() {
        String loggedUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        
        Contact dummyContact = new Contact();
        dummyContact.Firstname = 'Test';
        dummyContact.Lastname = 'Contact';
        dummyContact.Birthdate = date.today();
        INSERT dummyContact;

        Account dummyAcct = new Account();
        dummyAcct.Name = 'Test Company';
        dummyAcct.Custom__c = loggedUserId;
        INSERT dummyAcct;

        AccountContactRelation acr = new AccountContactRelation();
        acr.ContactId = dummyContact.Id;
        acr.Contact.Birthdate = dummyContact.Birthdate;
        acr.AccountId = dummyAcct.Id;
        acr.Account.Name = dummyAcct.Name;
        acr.Account.Custom__c = dummyAcct.Custom__c;
        INSERT acr;

        lifeEventNotifyController testCont = new lifeEventNotifyController ();
        List<AccountContactRelation> dummyList = testCont.getLifeEvents();

        System.assert(dummyList  != null);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clearly indicate which line throws the error. Without a stack trace, it is much harder to help you.

Comment: I just saw this note, @AdrianLarson, thanks for the tip. I will do this next time. It was `Class.lifeEventNotifyControllerTest.TestSOQL: line 25, column 1`

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Once you get this cleared up, please be sure to take the [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour), look in the [Help Center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help), and contribute with answers to others' questions if you can. Also, when someone asks for clarification in the comments, or you come up with more information on your own (e.g., you tried something that did not work, you did something that gave a different error) please edit your question to add the information - it can be missed if you answer in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be in how you set the `AccountContactRelationship.AccountId` lookup. Specifically, you are trying to set both that field (which you do correctly), but also set `Account.Name` and `Account.Custom__c`, which are incorrect. Simply remove the lines which set those fields, as they appear to be the only possible source of any `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Because the `Account` name has already been declared within the `dummyAcct` variable, I don't need to declare it again in `AccountContactRelation` as it's a junction object. Right on.

Comment: I now have a new error: `INVALID_PERSON_ACCOUNT_OPERATION` which appears to be because I am trying to test on the `Contact` object rather than the `Account` object where `IsPersonAccount = TRUE`. I will troubleshoot that next, but in the meantime, thank you for your quick reply!

Comment: Yeah sounds like you need to set a specific `RecordType`.